# Horizontal scroll on overflow of table

Tags: html, css, styling, usability

I have a basic table in a container. The table will have about 25 columns. I am trying to add a horizontal scroll bar on overflow of the table and am having a really tough time.

What is happening now, is the table cells are accommodating the cells contents by automatically adjusting the height of the cell and maintaining a fixed table width.

I appreciate any suggestions on why my method is not working on  how to fix this.

CSS

```
.search-table-outter {margin-bottom:30px; }
.search-table{table-layout: fixed; margin:40px auto 0px auto;  overflow-x:scroll; }
.search-table, td, th{border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #777;}
th{padding:20px 7px; font-size:15px; color:#444; background:#66C2E0;}
td{padding:5px 10px; height:35px;}
tr:nth-child(even)  {background: #f5f5f5;}
tr:nth-child(odd)   {background: #FFF;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="search-table-outter wrapper">
    <table class="search-table inner">
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
            <th>col4</th>
            <th>col5</th>
            <th>col5</th>
        </tr>
        <?php echo $rows; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS fiddle (Note: if possible, I would like the horizontal scroll bar to be in the container with the red border):
http://jsfiddle.net/ZXnqM/3/

Comment: If you use [the right CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451601/12917821), you can get rid of the wrapper.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I think your `overflow` should be on the outer container. You can also explicitly set a min width for the columns. Like this:

```css
.search-table-outter { overflow-x: scroll; }
th, td { min-width: 200px; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5WsEt/

Answer (score 105):

#### The solution for those who cannot or do not want to wrap the `table` in a `div` (e.g. if the HTML is generated from Markdown) but still want to have scrollbars:

```css
table {
  display: block;
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Especially on mobile, a table can easily become wider than the viewport.</td>
    <td>Using the right CSS, you can get scrollbars on the table without wrapping it.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A centered table.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Explanation: `display: block;` makes it possible to have scrollbars. By default (and unlike tables), blocks span the full width of the parent element. This can be prevented with `max-width: fit-content;`, which allows you to still horizontally center tables with less content using `margin: 0 auto;`. `white-space: nowrap;` is optional (but useful for this demonstration).

Comment: This really work perfect for markdown without using table wrapper like other answers.

Comment: This worked straight away for table added via WYSIWYG editor, where there was no wrapper, and adding one would have been a mountain of work. Thanks @Kaspar Etter

Comment: Thanks. All this time. I was missing `display:block;`

Comment: Note that this solution is not good for accessibility ([explanation](https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-what-css-display-properties-do-to-table-semantics/))

Comment: Keep in mind that changing display from `table` to `block` might affect the table's children. For example, I ran into problem that children don't occupy full container's width.

Comment: In Chrome, when you change `table` to `display:block;`, Chrome ignores the `<thead>` element, treating it instead as `<tbody>`. Any CSS that targets `<thead>` will no longer work!

Comment: Can you provide an example, @Martin_W? I have no problems styling `<thead>` elements with the above CSS.

Comment: Ah, @KasparEtter, you are right... I stand corrected. I had a typo in my HTML markup! `<thead>` styling via CSS fine.

Comment: @clhenrick Is that still accurate? I'm unable to reproduce the issue when setting display: block on a table. It still shows up as a table in the accessibility pane in Chrome 98, and its children still retain their roles.

Comment: In the days of flex and grid its nice to see a good old fashion solution.I used to slap the table in a wrapper with overflow but this is so much more appealing!

Answer (score 22):

A solution that nobody mentioned is use [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for the table and add `overflow-x` to the wrapper.

(http://jsfiddle.net/xc7jLuyx/11/)

**CSS**

```
.wrapper { overflow-x: auto; }
.wrapper table { white-space: nowrap; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table></table>
</div>
```

*This is an ideal scenario if you don't want rows with multiple lines. 

To add break lines you need to use `<br/>`*.

Comment: I didn't have to use `white-space: nowrap`, but I was trying to use `overflow-x: scroll` on the table itself. Your suggestion to make a container for the table and use it there saved me. TY

Answer (score 7):

Unless I grossly misunderstood your question, move `overflow-x:scroll` from `.search-table` to `.search-table-outter`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXnqM/4/

```
.search-table-outter {border:2px solid red; overflow-x:scroll;}
.search-table{table-layout: fixed; margin:40px auto 0px auto;   }
```

As far as I know you can't give scrollbars to tables themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Close, but not exactly, because the height of the cells (`<td>`) are still automatically adjusted, note even if `max-height:35px;` cells are way taller than 35px...

Answer (score 0):

```
   .search-table-outter {border:2px solid red; overflow-x:scroll;}
   .search-table{table-layout: fixed; margin:40px auto 0px auto;   }
   .search-table, td, th{border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #777;}
   th{padding:20px 7px; font-size:15px; color:#444; background:#66C2E0;}
   td{padding:5px 10px; height:35px;}
```

You should provide scroll in div.

Answer (score -4):

On a responsive site for mobiles the whole thing has to be positioned absolute on a relative div. And fixed height. Media Query set for relevance.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .scroll-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    overflow-x:scroll;
  }
```